# How to use dataflow text io dynamic destinations in java

Tags: scala, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Hello i am very confused By the dynamic file destinations api and there is no docs so here i am.

The situation is i have a PCollection and it contains events belonging to different partitions. I want to split them up and write them to different folders in gcs.

Here is what i have.

Dynamic destination object:

```
  class GCSDestinationString(prefix: String) extends DynamicDestinations[Event, String, String] {

    override def getDestination(element: Event): String = {
      element.partition //this returns a string which is a gcs folder path
    }

    override def getFilenamePolicy(destination: String): FileBasedSink.FilenamePolicy = {
      println(destination)
      val overallPrefix = s"$prefix/$destination/part-"
      DefaultFilenamePolicy.fromStandardParameters(
        ValueProvider.StaticValueProvider.of(
          FileSystems.matchNewResource(overallPrefix, false)),
        null, ".jsonl", true)
    }

    override def formatRecord(record: Event): String = {
      implicit val f = DefaultFormats
      write(record.toDataLakeFormat())
    }

    override def getDefaultDestination: String = "default"
  }
```

I believe this is the correct logic, i ask each element what its destination partition is and then that get passed into the getFileNamePolicy and from there a file name is built. To format the record i just convert it to json.

The issue is integrating this with TextIO, i tried this

```
TextIO.
  write()
  .withWindowedWrites()
  .withTempDirectory(tempDir)
  .to(new GCSDestinationString("gcs://bucket"))
```

but it requires that the source type be string, technically this could work but i would have to deserialise multiple times. I found in the docs for text io dynamic destinations

`Often this is used in conjunction with {@link TextIO#writeCustomType}, which allows your {@link DynamicDestinations} object to examine the input type and takes a format function to convert that type to a string for writing.`

So lets try that

```
  TextIO
    .writeCustomType[Event]()
    .withWindowedWrites()
    .withTempDirectory(tempDir)
    .to(new GCSDestinationString("gcs://bucket"))
```

This still doesn't compile as writeCustomType internally returns `TypedWrite<UserT, Void>` and that has the knock on affect of requiring the  2nd type parameter of my dynamic destination object to be Void. Clearly i require it to be a string or at least something other than Void

Im clearly missing something

Comment: Your second code snippet should compile. TypedWrite.to(DynamicDestinations) changes the destination type: public <NewDestinationT> TypedWrite<UserT, NewDestinationT> to(        DynamicDestinations<UserT, DestinationT, String> dynamicDestinations). Can you include the full compile error message? Alternatively, you can also give a try to FileIO.write() (added on master yesterday) which has a more convenient API - see https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.java#L279 and use TextIO.sink(). You'll need version 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT for that.

Answer (score 3):

Oh man, this is embarrassing. Turns out `writeCustomType().to(DynamicDestinations)` was not tested and we didn't notice it, but it had a typo in the type signature. PR https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/4319 is in review. You'll still need 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT to pick it up though, in which case I would still recommend to just use `FileIO.write()`.

Comment: Ok makes sense, does my answer have the same affect what is the difference between the two APIs

Comment: DynamicDestinations is more general, e.g. you can use side inputs in your mapping.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to compile in scala but i was able to get the behaviour i wanted with a similar api after digging around

```
 var outputTransform =
        TextIO.
          writeCustomType[T]()
          .withFormatFunction(outputFormatter)
          .withNumShards(shards)
          .withTempDirectory(tempDir)
          .withCompression(compression)

      if (windowedWrites) {
        outputTransform = outputTransform.withWindowedWrites()
      }

      outputTransform.to(outputFileNamePolicyMapping, emptryDestination)
```

where output formatter is from T to string and outputFileNamePolicyMapping is from T to DefaultFilenamePolicy.Params

Answer (score 1):

Following @jkff advice on the [Apache Beam Mailing List](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/e9dba5ad56ae02f0d235e6c20a27028d3a99db617cd9336d66182f65@%3Cuser.beam.apache.org%3E) I managed to get it compiling and working this way:

```java
val write = TextIO.writeCustomType[Event].asInstanceOf[TextIO.TypedWrite[Event, String]]
    .to(new MyDynamicDestinations(baseDir))
```

Although after doing it that way I realised it is more convenient to use a `DefaultFilenamePolicy.Params` instead of a `String` as the destination output. Let me know if you want more information about that bit.